# Merge a feature branch locally to continue work while it's in code review on remote

Tags: git, github, version-control, project-management

Lets say I'm on `master`; I make a feature branch derived from it and open a PR for code review. While waiting on the approval, I want to merge the feature branch on my local `master` and continue working on other things that requires that feature. The changes are really straightforward and will not be affected in the work I'm planning to do locally.

How do I do that?

Comment: Have you got the answer which helps you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer. And it will also benefit other members who meet similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to execute below command to get the merged commit from github and keep the local commits on local `master` branch.

```
#on local master branch
git pull origin master --rebase
```

Assume after you merged feature branch into your local `master` branch (as commit `M`) and commit changes on `master` branch (as commits `G` and `H`), the commit history as below:

```
...---A---B---C---M---G---H  master 
       \         /
        D---E---F    feature
```

After the PR is completed, there will also has a merged commit (assume it's `M'`) on github/remote `master` branch.

In order to pull the commit `M'` from remote repo into your local repo while keeping your local changes (commits `G` and `H`) on `master` branch, you can use the command `git pull origin master --rebase` on `master` branch. Then the commit history in your local repo will be:

```
...---A---B---C---M'---G'---H'  master 
       \         /
        D---E---F    feature
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use rebase and fetch to take last commit and modification locally, or merge that's same way to combine between remote and local, just one difference of them that merge will create new commit.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the 'flow'. Some review tools have poor support for rebase (github, for one), some are really good with it (gerrit, bitbucket). Why? Because rebase changes history. Let's assume

```
master
      -feature              -review changes
              -dependent feature
```

When rebasing you are moving the reference (parent commit) of -dependent feature from -feature to -review changes, hence altering the history. This is very different from merge. There is good article about the differences [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing), but I recommend reading the [book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Now, I would open up a branch from -feature (as described in the diagram), but would rebase on master before opening a PR request (less chance of conflict when approved) for -dependent feature, having -feature merged to master.

Be careful when using rebase, as **altering history can lead to a nightmare**. If you alter a commit that someone else pulled and worked on top of it, he/she is going to hate you a lot. Don't rebase commits that are merged on common branches (master/develop).

Hope this helps.